# rosjava: calling rosservice fails

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I made my first homebrewed rosservice with Java. I have generated my custom service GetCylinders.srv

```
 ---
 string name
 float32 likelihood
```

which should return a name and a likelihood with an empty request. I have generated the service and included it in my server like this:

```
 import org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.*;

   ServiceServer<org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Request, org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Response> server = node.newServiceServer(
        "callme", "reasoner_msgs/GetCylinders",
        
        new ServiceResponseBuilder<org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Request, org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Response>() {
          @Override
          public org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Response build(org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Request request) throws ServiceException {
            org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Response response = new org.ros.service.reasoner_msgs.GetCylinders.Response();
            // ...
            response.name="CylinderA";
            response.likelihood=(float) 0.7;
            
            return response;
          }
        }
);
```

When I start the node the service /callme shows up. Well that is fine. But if I use rosservice call /callme i get an error. Have I done something wrong in the setup of the service? The error message I get is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosservice", line 46, in <module>
rosservice.rosservicemain()
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 731, in rosservicemain
_rosservice_cmd_call(argv)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 586, in _rosservice_cmd_call
service_class = get_service_class_by_name(service_name)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 357, in get_service_class_by_name
service_type = get_service_type(service_name)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 141, in get_service_type
return get_service_headers(service_name, service_uri).get('type', None)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosservice/src/rosservice.py", line 113, in get_service_headers
return roslib.network.read_ros_handshake_header(s, cStringIO.StringIO(), 2048)
 File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/network.py", line 367, in read_ros_handshake_header
raise ROSHandshakeException("connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. %s bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details."%b.tell())
 roslib.network.ROSHandshakeException: connection from sender terminated before handshake header received. 0 bytes were received. Please check sender for additional details.
```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27573/rosjava:-calling-rosservice-fails/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-02-14**:
I found out that using rosservice info /callme and rosservice args /callme give the same error. rosservice list shows /callme and rosservice uri /callme gives rosrpc://127.0.0.1:53311. Strange. Is there maybe a bug in the rosjavas service call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably related to http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=75

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2